# PHP - remove facebook app / logout

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

So, my website app is working, but the unlink/logout functionality is not. On my app page, I have an "Unlink" link, which posts to a method in my code, and within that, I do some housekeeping, and generate a Facebook "Log Out URL":

```
   $fbParams = [
                    'app_id'                => <my app id>,
                    'app_secret'            => <ma app secret>,
                    'default_graph_version' => 'v2.3'
                ];
    $this->fb = new Facebook\Facebook( $fbParams );


    $helper = $this->fb->getRedirectLoginHelper();
    $logout_url = $helper->getLogoutUrl(<my access token>, $my_url);

    return header("Location:" . $logout_url);
```

$my_url is the correct url back into my website. The appId and Secret are correct. When I run this, there are two problems:

1) The app stays attached to the Facebook account ( on Settings->apps, in the bar on the top, the app is still present.

2) Instead of going to the URL I specified, it just draws up my Facebook page.

Any suggestions? The "Deauthorize Callback URL" works perfectly, btw.

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, what I did want is to have the user remove the app from his/her approved apps, NOT log out of Facebook. It's the ability to 'unlink' that I was attempting to implement, and I did get it working. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

For your first point: that is intended. You want the user to only log out, not remove your app from their approved apps.

For your second point; can you set up an example page? Also, can you try using a link to click on instead of a header redirect?

```
$helper = $fb->getRedirectLoginHelper();

$logoutUrl = $helper->getLogoutUrl('{access-token}', 'http://example.com');
echo '<a href="' . $logoutUrl . '">Logout of Facebook!</a>';
```

**Please note:** this method will end the **whole** Facebook session. This means that the user will be logged out from your app. This is probably not something you want to do, since it can be annoying for the user. So please think twice before implementing this.